# Can't add user to aspnet_Users database using Membership provider WPF

Tags: sql, database, connection, membership

Hy everyone,

I've created a membreship database in the SQL Server (using aspnet_regsql), so server side wise, all is ok.
I've fallowed this video tutorial http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=293710 to make a WPF app that verifies a username and password in the SQL database.

I have added this in my app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="UserManagementCS" connectionString="Server=MyServer; Database=db_membership; uid=user;pwd=user;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <add name="LoginProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="UserManagementCS" 
             applicationName="Login" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             passwordFormat="Hashed" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
 </system.web>
```

but, I've a problem... I can't get the user to be created in the SQL Database. Instead the aplication creates a local ASPNETDB.mdf where it stores the user.

Does anybody have any ideea why my connection towards the db isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this detailed post from Scott Guthrie:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx

Comment: I've checked the connection string and it points to the right db... somehow I still can't access it through Membership... I've done the steps in the link and have the database with all the needed tables... I still have the local db that is created when I launch the app

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your application is looking at the connectionstring with name `Application Services`, which has a default database. Change that connection string to point to your database and everything should work.